# Intellij Idea 13.x and ASM 5.x library incompatible?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, java-bytecode-asm

### I can't get Intellij Idea 13.0 to compile my code against ASM 5.0.3

I have a multi-module Maven project. It compiles and installs successfully.

Apparently `com.google.findbugs:findbugs` has a dependency on `asm:asm:3.3` and I want to use `org.ow2.asm:asm:5.0.3` to manipulate some bytecode.

So in the parent `pom.xml` I exclude the `asm:asm:3.3` dependencies from the classpath. This works fine when I run `mvn install` from the command line.

I can't get the *Build -> Make Project* menu selection to work in Intellij Idea.

Here is the relevant parts of my `pom.xml` files.

#### parent.pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
    <artifactId>asm-tree</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
    <artifactId>asm-util</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
    <artifactId>asm-commons</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.3</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
    <artifactId>findbugs</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm-commons</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm-tree</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

#### Here is the code that is failing

```
18       public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException 
19       { 
20           final InputStream is = NotEmptyTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/vertigrated/annotation/NotEmptyTest.class"); 
21           final ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(is); 
22           final ClassNode cn = new ClassNode(); 
23           cr.accept(cn, 0); 
24           for (final MethodNode mn : cn.methods)
25           { 
26 - 38 snipped for brevity 
39           } 
40       } 
41   }
```

#### Here is the error message:

```
Information:Using javac 1.7.0_25 to compile java sources
Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'tests'
Information:Compilation completed with 1 error and 2 warnings in 2 sec
Information:1 error
Information:2 warnings
/<path to my source code>/NotEmptyTest.java
    Error:Error:line (24)java: incompatible types
  required: org.objectweb.asm.tree.MethodNode
  found:    java.lang.Object
    Warning:Warning:java: /<path to my project>//NotEmptyTest.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
    Warning:Warning:java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

#### As you can see in the screen capture, it reports the correct version of the libraries in the Javadoc but the AutoComplete shows the old `3.3` non-typesafe return value of `List` instead of `List<MethodNode>`:

[image: JavaDoc PopUp]
<sub>(source: [vertigrated.com](http://www.vertigrated.com/images/Voila_Capture%202014-05-26_04-38-45_PM.png))</sub>

#### Here is what Maven knows, which is correct:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:list (default-cli) @ tests ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] The following files have been resolved:
[INFO]    com.google.code.findbugs:bcel:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO]    junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO]    xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO]    com.apple:AppleJavaExtensions:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO]    javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO]    jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1.6:compile
[INFO]    org.ow2.asm:asm-util:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO]    com.google.inject:guice:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO]    dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO]    com.google.code.findbugs:jFormatString:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO]    net.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO]    org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO]    commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO]    com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO]    org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO]    aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO]    com.google.code.findbugs:findbugs:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO]    org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO]    org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.3:compile
```

### How do I get Intellij Idea to use the correct dependency internally?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you end up having `asm-5.0.3.jar` in your compilation class path in IntelliJ IDEA.
This JAR is optimized for minimal size by stripping every bit of it that could be stripped, including the generic signatures (that's how a `List<MethodNode>` becomes a `List`, which is effectively `List<Object>` in your case).

To make sure this is the case, try replacing the dependencies on `asm`, `asm-tree` etc by [`asm-debug-all`](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.ow2.asm%7Casm-debug-all%7C5.0.3%7Cjar). The JAR you get will be bigger, but the project should compile now.

Next question is how this compiles in `mvn`, but fails in IntelliJ IDEA. You can see the class path in the "Project Structure" dialog under "Modules", on the "Dependencies" tab. Maybe the class path was not imported correctly in IntelliJ (in that case, report to IntelliJ IDEA's [issue tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA), you'll probably get some help rather soon).