# Iterating a List<String> using a forloop (Java)

Tags: java

Im trying to iterate a List. Im working with ASM, and usually I use

```
for(MethodNode methodNode:(List<MethodNode>) classNode.methods){
     //...
}
```

to iterate my Lists.

but when I try to iterate a List of String's

```
for(String interfaceName:(List<String>) classNode.interfaces){
     //...
}
```

my IDE gives me "Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable" error.

@Params classNode.interfaces returns a `List <String>`(http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/tree/ClassNode.html#interfaces)

Edit:
I figured it out! For those who were wondering what I did I figured Id post it!

```
for(Object strName: classNode.interfaces){
     //use String.valueOf(strName) to obtain type string
}
```

Comment: Can you show code for `classNode` ?

Comment: ClassNode is a class inside the ASM api, im currently using ASM5. classNode.interfaces returns a List<String>

Comment: if `classNode.interfaces` is a `List<String>` , you don't have to cast it again. Just `for ( String interfaceName : classNode.interfaces )` will work.

Comment: I see no difference between the logic of the code you've shown. The cast definitely isn't needed, though

Comment: @svasa Same goes for `methods`. Unless OP is using a really old version.

Comment: When removing the cast from the classNode.interfaces, I recieve a "Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to String" error from my IDE.

    for(String s:classNode.interfaces){

   }

Comment: What version are you using? Can you update it?

Comment: Im using java 8, with ASM 5.2

Comment: From the error `"Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to String"` It seems your `classNode.interfaces` isn't `List<String>` It is `List<Object>`. You need to provide full details of your code in order to get help.

Comment: What IDE are you using? If you have a CLI build script, is it giving the same error as the IDE?

Comment: It says right on the website "List<String>  interfaces
The internal names of the class's interfaces (see getInternalName)." So how is it of the type Object? And im using Eclipse kepler. I do not have a CLI script, I can try to do that and see if that will produce any other results, thank you for your input. Any idea on how I could make my IDE ignore the error if it truly is not an compiler error? Thank you everyone for all your help!

Comment: Seems like a possible case of this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23877521/intellij-idea-13-x-and-asm-5-x-library-incompatible

Answer (score 0):

This happens because for whatever reasons, the asm binary distribution comes with a jar stripped of generic signatures metadata. For development purposes, you should add `asm-debug-all-5.2.jar` to your classpath, then your IDE won't complain at you and you won't have to make strings out of things which are already strings. Here's the difference queried from each archive with `javap`

```
➤ javap -cp asm-all-5.2.jar org.objectweb.asm.tree.ClassNode | grep interfaces
  public java.util.List interfaces;
➤ javap -cp asm-debug-all-5.2.jar org.objectweb.asm.tree.ClassNode | grep interfaces
  public java.util.List<java.lang.String> interfaces;
```